# What to call the Alt+F2 mode in Unity?

Tags: discussion

I am looking for a consensus on what to call the Alt+F2 mode.

It seems that quite a few questions simply refer to it as Alt+F2 which is a bit clunky. Looking around I have also seen the following used:

- Dash 'special mode'
- Run Dialog
- Run Application

As most of the answers I post are tailored to Unity I have been using **Dash Run** in [answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39843/application-indicator-for-shutter/39854#39854) since it made sense to me at the time of writing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I always used "Run Command" to refer to this, since that's what it does and referred to by the `gnome-panel` version.

Comment: I talked to Neil about this (the dash maintainer) and he says "Run Command" is correct.

Answer (score 3):

The inline text says "Run a command" so I myself decided to call it the "Run a command"-dialog. But I do like the **Dash Run** more than any of the others. So +1 on that.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think calling it anything is just unnecessary and if anything would cause confusion. Because we need to mention that you press Alt+F2 to get there - no need to add a name for it.

[In this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39843/application-indicator-for-shutter/39854#39854) I think the added 'Dash Run' text is confusing (it is to me at least).

Seeing as we don't have an official name for this, I think it would be better not to call it anything.

Answer (score 0):

If we were going to settle on a name, then seeing as we have the "Applications Lens" and "Files & Folders Lens" then I would suggest *Command Lens* or *Run Lens*.